# Is it Mutar to do Shehiya and Chazara on Sternos?

Tags: cooking-bishul

Assuming the the water in the bottom pan is Yad Soledes Bo before Shabbos would it be Mutar to do Shehiya for the Friday night Shalom Zachar or the like on top of [Sternos?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwicuJW8xqPYAhVIct8KHZV1DBcQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FSterno-7-Ounce-Entertainment-Cooking-6-Pack%2Fdp%2FB00504ASOE&psig=AOvVaw3CUpwsiJMWHrO5X19uy-Tt&ust=1514235899755400)

I was primarily thinking that maybe it should be Mutar based on the fact that you don't stir the fuel in a sterno so it should be equivalent to [Kash Ugevava - straw and stubble](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.253.1?lang=he&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he). Additionally, nobody ever cooks on a Sterno.

Additionally, a friend of mine wanted to say that you should be allowed to do Nesina Lechatchillah because it should be considered a Kedeira Al Gabei Kedeira (assuming you fulfill the conditions) since you're putting it on top of a pan of hot water. Is that a valid point?

Comment: I may not be following this exact scenario, so, please confirm or edit. Most people place a sterno under a pan of hot water, and then the food pan is inserted on top of the hot water pan. Thus, the food is a *kli shieni* for which there is no "cooking". Of course, the water needs to have been boiled prior to the start of Shabbat. Are you talking about placing the already cooked food directly on the sterno before Shabbat, thus making that a *kli rishon*? If so, sounds like it has the same chazara rules as the blech. Why would a sterno be different?

Comment: I'm not sure that we're on the same page here because what you described sounds like a Kli Rishon She'al Gabbei Ha'aish.